# How to avoid adding duplicate data to db when using EFCore.BulkExtensions?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, efcore.bulkextensions

I am using `EFCore.BulkExtensions` in .NET Core 3.1 with Entity Framework Core.

I have a list containing records that already exist in my database, as well as records that are new and do not yet exist in my database.

I want to only add the new records to my database. I am currently managing to add the new records but I am also unfortunately adding the old ones, meaning duplicates are made in the table.

I have a domain object called `InstagramInsightDatum` that looks like this and a table in my database to reflect it:

```
public int InstagramInsightDatumId { get; set; }
public int Value { get; private set; }
public DateTime EndTime { get; private set; }
public int InstagramInsightId { get; set; }
public InstagramInsight InstagramInsight { get; set; }
```

I want to only add new `InstagramInsightDatums` to the database when they are unique. I will never need to update these records, just add new ones. At the moment my code looks like this:

[image]

I've highlighted the line where I add these datums to the table where the duplicates are happening in red - here you can see I am making the bulkInsert with the `InstagramInsightDatums`, and setting the `PropertiesToExclude` to `InstagramInsightDatumId` (I am not 100% how this config is meant to work but I assumed this feature is to allow us to ignore certain properties when comparing data?) - as removing the PK from the properties should reveal any potential duplicates...

Can anyone see why this isn't working?

Comment: You can't. By *definition* bulk operations work in bulk. What you ask isn't `just`. You can't ignore duplicates with an `INSERT .. VALUES` clause either. The *only* real bulk operation, BULK INSERT, works because it uses minimal logging. This means that instead of logging each table change, entire table pages are logged at a time, reducing the logging overhead.

Comment: To avoid duplication or errors, you'd have to *search* for duplicates either by ID or using a query. That's no longer a bulk operation.

Answer (score 0):

A bit old Question, but here's how you would do it: Use `UpdateByProperties` instead of `PropertiesToExclude` and set `PropertiesToIncludeOnUpdate = new List<string> { "" }`. If you do like this, the records with an *InstagramInsightDatumId* that's not already exists in db will be inserted, and nothing will happen with the ones already existing. Example below:

```
BulkConfig bulkConfig = new BulkConfig
{
    UpdateByProperties = new List<string>() { nameof(InstagramInsightDatum.InstagramInsightDatumId ),
    PropertiesToIncludeOnUpdate = new List<string> { "" }
};

_dataContext.BulkInsertOrUpdate(newFormattedDatums, bulkConfig);
```

Comment: this isn't going to work on .net core 3.1 because there is no "PropertiesToIncludeOnUpdate" option in 3.1 version)

Answer (score 0):

You can try: SqlBulkCopyOptions = SqlBulkCopyOptions.CheckConstraints

```
_dbContext.BulkInsertOrUpdate(entities, new BulkConfig
  {
    SqlBulkCopyOptions = SqlBulkCopyOptions.CheckConstraints
  });
```